# Read binary file in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I want to read a binary file and display the result in a memo but not how to do with this error: "Incompatible types: 'string' and 'Array'", the code is this

```
unit yo;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  F: TFileStream;
  Buffer: array [0 .. 1023] of byte;
begin

  F := TFileStream.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)
      + 'yo.exe', fmOpenRead);

  while F.Position < F.Size do
  begin

    F.Read(Buffer, 1024);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Buffer);

  end;

  F.Free;

end;
```

managed to avoid this error and to run the program without errors ?

anyone can help me?

Comment: Well, what is the encoding of the text in the file?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It's not text. The poster is trying to display the content of an .EXE file in a memo in 1K byte lines. ???

Comment: ...so the text embedded in the EXE is probably UTF-16, isn't it?

Comment: Ken White, yes, what I'm trying to do but I that error "Incompatible types: 'string' and 'Array'"

Comment: OK, so what encoding do you want to use to interpret the file?

Comment: You can't overcome this directly, because an `array[] of Byte` can't be assigned to a `string`, which is what `Memo.Lines` contain. `string` types are designed to hold `Char` values, not `Byte` arrays. You'd have to convert each individual `Byte` value to a `Char` using `Chr(Buffer[Index])`, and add each character to a string, and then pass the entire string to `Memo1.Lines.Add`. I'm not sure what value putting an executable's binary content into a `Memo` which is designed to hold **text** would be, though. Can you explain your goal here?

Comment: I'm going to guess that you're going on some old information here.  In the old days displaying a binary file as text was something that might be useful on occasion.  Now, however, we are in the Unicode era, it's basically useless.  Ken White's answer is about as good as you're going to do but the text in the program is likely in Unicode and thus won't display properly anyway.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't directly bypass this error, because a `string` and an `array[] of Byte` are not directly assignable.

Since binary content (the `#0` character in particular, or the `0x00` hex value (C/C++)) won't be displayable in a `TMemo` anyway (the text would be terminated at the first `#0` value), you'd need to replace it with something.

The *easiest* way to get past the compiler error is to change your array from `array[] of Byte` to `array[] of AnsiChar`, which can be directly assigned to a `string` (or typecast to one):

```
var
  Buffer: array[0..1023] of AnsiChar;
  TempStr: string;
begin
  // Fill buffer from stream
  TempStr := Buffer;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(TempStr);
  // The next line eliminates the need for `TempStr`
  // Memo1.Lines.Add(String(Buffer));
end;
```

However, like I said, this won't solve the problem of displaying in the memo. For instance, when actually reading a Windows executable, the first buffer displays `MZP`, because the fourth byte is a `#0` and the memo terminates the string.

To overcome this limitation, you need to replace all `#0` characters with something else. The problem with that, of course, is that any value you replace it with can also actually occur in the executable (since they're bytes, there are only 256 possible values). Again, the simple solution is to replace all `#0` characters with `0` (#216):

```
var
  Buffer: array[0..1023] of AnsiChar;
  i: Integer;
  TempStr: string;
begin
  // Fill buffer as before
  for i := Low(Buffer) to High(Buffer) do
    if Buffer[i] = #0 then
      Buffer[i] := `Ø`;        // Try #144 instead
  TempStr := Buffer;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(TempStr);
  // You can still eliminate the string variable by typecasting
  // Memo1.Lines.Add(String(TempStr));
end;
```

Here's code for a `TForm.FormCreate` event that actually reads a 1K buffer from a Delphi console application, does the above replacement, and displays the content in a `TMemo`. Drop the `TMemo` on a form, set its `Alignment` property to `alClient`, and `ScrollBars` to `ssVertical`. Add a `FormCreate` event handler to the form, and use the following code for that event:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Stream: TFileStream;
  Buffer: array[0..1023] of AnsiChar;
  TempStr: string;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
  // Populate buffer elements
  Stream := TFileStream.Create('D:\Temp\Project2.exe', fmOpenRead);
  try
    Stream.Read(Buffer[0], SizeOf(Buffer));
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
  // Replace null (#0) values with #216 (Ø)
  for i := Low(Buffer) to High(Buffer) do
    if Buffer[i] = #0 then
      Buffer[i] := 'Ø';
  TempStr := Buffer;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(TempStr);
end;
```

NOTE: If you're actually reading the entire binary file instead of just the first buffer, the last buffer might not be entirely full of the file content (you might not read a full buffer on the last pass). In that case, you want to mark the end of the buffer with a `#0` so that the memo correctly displays that partial buffer. You can change the `for` loop to use something like this:

```
for i := Low(Buffer) to High(Buffer) do
begin
  if (i = BytesRead) then
  begin
    Buffer[i] := #0;   // Mark the end of the buffer and exit loop; 
    Break;
  end
  else if (Buffer[i] = #0) then
   Buffer[i] := 'Ø';
end;
```

Here's the output of reading a single buffer full:

[image: Executable displayed in TMemo]

Answer (score 7):

An array of bytes is not a string, so the compiler's message means exactly what it says. Bytes are numeric; strings are textual. Numbers aren't text, so somewhere in the process, you need to tell your program how to convert the numbers into text.

One way is to convert each numeric value into its corresponding digits. For example:

```
F.Read(Buffer, 1024);
s := '';
for b in Buffer do
  s := s + IntToStr(b);
Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
```

If you want each byte to be converted to the *character* with the corresponding numeric value, then you don't really need any conversion at all; just lie and tell the program that the file contains text so you can load it directly into the memo control:

```
Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(FileName);
```

If you want the bytes in the file that can represent printable characters to be displayed as-is, and the ones that represent non-printable characters to be displayed numerically, then you can process each character separately, similarly to the loop above:

```
F.Read(Buffer, 1024);
s := '';
for b in Buffer do begin
  c := AnsiChar(b);
  if TCharacter.IsControl(c) then
    s := s + IntToStr(b)
  else
    s := s + c;
end;
Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
```

You can define the data conversion any way you want. All you have to do is specify what output you want, and then write the code that generates it. If you haven't specified what you want, and you can't describe it accurately, then you're not ready for the code yet.

Comment: I declared `buffer: byte;` but I get error `E2430 for-in statement cannot operate on collection type 'Byte'` What type I should use for `buffer` ?

Comment: The question declared `Buffer` as a fixed-size array of bytes. If it's only one `Byte`, then there would be no need to iterate over it. What did you expect, @zac?

Comment: just to make sure array of bytes